# How do i muliply any declare variable by -1 in 'case' statement?

Tags: sql

I have @myvar with following query how do i multiply (@myvar * -1) in following query.

```
SELECT 
      Date,   
      case when Position > 0 then
            Position * Mark * case when SecurityType in ('Equity','Equity Option') Then Mark * 100 else 1 end
      else
            0
      end var,
      case when Position < 0 then
            Position * Mark * case when SecurityType in ('Equity','Equity Option') Then .Mark * 100 else 1 end
      else
            0
      end (@myvar * -1),Id FROM Mytable
```

-- I'm getting error

help me :)

Comment: If they are 3 columns in a result set are you not missing a comma after `Date` and the `End` preceding `(@myvar * -1)`?  (You can also just `-@myvar`)

Comment: @alex after date there are 20 columns yes , is there but i just want to know how can i multiply -1 to myvar ???

Comment: `SELECT a,b,c,-@myvar` is fine provided the delimiting commas are correct

Comment: case when Position < 0 then
-1 *  Position * Mark * case when SecurityType in ('Equity','Equity Option') Then Mark * 100 else 1 end**
  else
        0
  end  Myvar , -- myvar will be (-) because in above condition i multiply -1
  Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey all i got the answer

I just need to do

```
    case when Position < 0 then
    -1 *  Position * Mark * case when SecurityType in ('Equity','Equity Option') Then Mark * 100 else 1 end**
      else
            0
      end  Myvar , -- myvar will be (-) because in above condition i multiply -1
      Id
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma after your last end to specify a new column. If you're just returning -1 * myvar, then the expression you have is correct.

```
SELECT 
      Date,   
      case when Position > 0 then
            Position * Mark * case when SecurityType in ('Equity','Equity Option') Then Mark * 100 else 1 end
      else
            0
      end var,
      case when Position < 0 then
            Position * Mark * case when SecurityType in ('Equity','Equity Option') Then Mark * 100 else 1 end
      else
            0
      end,
      (@myvar * -1) -- I'm getting error
```

Comment: Also missing a , after `Date`

Comment: last statement is like 
  end myvar,
      Id

Comment: `end @myvar` is not legal, you need an operator `end + ??` or a comma - you need to expand your question

Comment: @alex i just want to multiply with -1 to myvar

Comment: case when Position < 0 then
-1 *  Position * Mark * case when SecurityType in ('Equity','Equity Option') Then Mark * 100 else 1 end**
  else
        0
  end  Myvar , -- myvar will be (-) because in above condition i multiply -1